# Actionscript 3.0 - Changing FPS for scenes won't work

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript, frame-rate, scene

I have a scene where if you push a button, it goes to a different scene.

At the beginning code of Scene 2, I have -

```
stage.frameRate = 40
```

But, to my surprise, it stays the same FPS!

Should there be a variable for it or something?

Comment: are you using Timeline or document class??

Comment: @Josh Harward - You can adjust the frame rate according to the scene as in the following example. Are you satisfied?

Comment: @Josh Harward - Does it work?

Comment: Yup, it works!  Thank you!  I've been too busy this past week to try it until now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Main Timeline being a `MovieClip`...

```
trace(this, this is MovieClip); // [object MainTimeline] true
```

you can use the [read-only] property [`currentScene`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/MovieClip.html#currentScene) of a MovieClip:

> "The current scene in which the playhead is located in the timeline of
>   the MovieClip instance."

...and the [read-only] property [`name`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/Scene.html#name) of a Scene:

> "The name of the scene."

**Scene 1**

```
function modifyFrameRate():void {
    stage.frameRate = this.currentScene.name == 'Scene 1' ? 2 : 40;
}
modifyFrameRate();
```

**Scene 2**

```
modifyFrameRate();
```

Adobe Help to read more about [Scene Class](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/Scene.html).