# Different Scene, different framerate in AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, frame-rate, scene

How do I make this code correct in different frame rate in 3 different scenes? Any examples?

Original from [Actionscript 3.0 - Changing FPS for scenes won't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25614068/actionscript-3-0-changing-fps-for-scenes-wont-work):

```
function modifyFrameRate():void {
    stage.frameRate = this.currentScene.name == 'Scene 1' ? 2 : 40;
}
modifyFrameRate();
```

My code:

```
function modifyFrameRate():void {
    stage.frameRate = this.currentScene.name == 'Title' ? 'Game' : 60;
    stage.frameRate = this.currentScene.name == 'Intro Scene' ? 'Game' : 60;
    stage.frameRate = this.currentScene.name == 'Game' ? 'Ending Scene' : 24;
}
modifyFrameRate();
```

Answer (score 1):

The original code chooses between two modes, that's why ternary operator is used. If you have more scenes, there's much more sense to create a **key:value** dictionary where scene names are the keys and the frame rates are values:

```
var SceneToRate:Object =
{
    'Title': 10,
    'Intro Scene': 120,
    'Game': 60,
    'Ending Scene': 24
}

function updateFrameRate():void
{
    stage.frameRate = SceneToRate[currentScene.name];
}
```